# Disc personality graph

Tags: javascript, plot, graph

[I need a Javascript library that will aid in plotting the type of graph in the image, has anyone come across such before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75cOb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Chart.js
Combine Line and Scatter graphs.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/line.html
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/scatter.html

Comment: Please how would I add the scales for the other y axis

Comment: Multi Axis-  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/scatter-multi-axis.html
There is a lot of customizability of these charts you should be able to easily replicate your desired chart.